# Read textbox value in knockout js

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am building a editable grid.
The Gift Name is a auto suggest textbox.

When I select a value and try to retrieve the value then it is not showing that value.
My Code is [here](http ://jsfiddle.net/bhagirathip/x6H8s/38/)

In the textbox select a value and click submit button.
It should show the 1st textbox value but it is showing null.

where i have made mistake .

-Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the real issue here is that `name` is not updated properly when you're using jQuery's autocomplete. You should change binding for `name`:

```
<input data-bind="value: name, valueUpdate: 'blur'" class='tags' />
```

The blur event occurs when an element loses focus. And each time when it will occur - KO will force binding to update value.

---

[KO Documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html):

> **valueUpdate**
>
> If your binding also includes a parameter called valueUpdate, this
>   defines additional browser events KO should use to detect changes
>   besides the change event.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your fiddle and you seem to be missing a couple of parentheses while calling `self.gifts()`.

This one:

```
self.save = function () {
    var abc = $.parseJSON(ko.toJSON({ gifts: self.gifts }));
    alert(abc.gifts[0].name);
};
```

Should be:

```
var abc = $.parseJSON(ko.toJSON({ gifts: self.gifts() }));
```

With the parentheses at the end.

You have to remember that `self.gifts = ko.observableArray(gifts);` returns *the value wrapped in a function*, so in order to access the value, you need to call `self.gifts()`.

Running this example will show an alert with an empty string, because you initialized your `gifts` array with an empty name value.

If you add a value to the name here:

```
var viewModel = new GiftModel([
    { name: "", price: "" }
]);
```

You would then display that name in the alert box. See updated jsfiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/uC7b6/).

Comment: You're not quite right on `push` statement. In this case we are using  knockout's `push` which works on `self.gifts.push({..`. If we change it to `self.gifts().push({` it will not update layout on adding new item..

Comment: Oh I see. I thought he was using the native Array.push statement. Updated.